# /fill command help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to remove a large quantity of blocks. Is there an easier way to do this than deleting all of your command blocks while trying to get `/fill` to work? I really don't want to use structure blocks. Can anybody help?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by getting /fill to work at the same time?

Comment: well to get /fill to work since im sorta new to useing that command i do trial and error...

Comment: and theres error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First I'll run you through how to use the fill command:**

Lets replace this 4x4 square with air
[image]
First find the coordinates of the bottom corner of the square:
The coordinates are in the highlighted box
[image]
Write this down and then lets find the top corner of the other side of the square[image]
[image]

When your done writing both coordinates down place them in a commandblock, it should look like this:

/fill 39.529 26 58.418 36.335 27 61.391

these are the two sets of coordinates (They can be rounded)
/fill (39.529 26 58.418) (36.335 27 61.391)

After this you have to place the name of the block you want to replace the square with, after the coordinates

/fill 39.5 26 58.5 36.3 27 61.3 minecraft:air

And poof it's gone
[image]

As for alternative ways this is one of the best, unless you want to download 3rd party tools like WorldEdit.